# This is ASYNC REQUEST. Can you help me change to Curl in php?

Tags: php, asynchronous, request

Here the details

https://api.offertest.net/offertest[?async=true]

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJvZUF1VU5yZVJXNmN5cHdKcGNnbmxRIiwiaWF0IjoxNTUxOTMxNzU3LCJqdGkiOiJUanNUaF9sUkY4MUR0VER5aWQ3bG9BIn0.DLgPiNNDHJMZTufUHS5nYTD_j3ImvxIfhMNrqlcl4LA" -X POST -d '{"userid":"oeAuUNreRW6cypwJpcgnlQ", "country":"us", "url":"http://www.google.com/","platform": "android", "callback":"http://{YOURAPIURL}/offertest/{YOURCAMPAIGNID}/result"}' -H "Content-type: application/json" https://api.offertest.net/offertest?async=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code :

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.offertest.net/offertest?async=true');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"userid\":\"oeAuUNreRW6cypwJpcgnlQ\", \"country\":\"us\", \"url\":\"http://www.google.com/\",\"platform\": \"android\", \"callback\":\"http://{YOURAPIURL}/offertest/{YOURCAMPAIGNID}/result\"}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJvZUF1VU5yZVJXNmN5cHdKcGNnbmxRIiwiaWF0IjoxNTUxOTMxNzU3LCJqdGkiOiJUanNUaF9sUkY4MUR0VER5aWQ3bG9BIn0.DLgPiNNDHJMZTufUHS5nYTD_j3ImvxIfhMNrqlcl4LA';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: thank you so much Ravi. It is working. :)